# Is JavaScript and NodeJs are Syncrhonous or Asyncrhonous?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If we look over internet, some websites say Javascript is syncrhonous and NodeJs is Asyncrhonous.

We can make async calls and can use promises both in JS and nodeJs then how one can be synchronous while the other is asyncrhonous. Or maybe if I am wrong then both are syncrhonous or both are asynchronous.

So, my Question is:

- Is NodeJs Syncrhonous or Asynchronous?
- Is javascript Syncrhonous or Asyncrhonous?

Comment: You should avoid these websites. I guess geeksforgeeks is one of them and probably dev.to is another. Node.js is a JavaScript runtime environment. How could we answer your question? You have to ask the people who made these nonsense statements.

Comment: Whatever, justify whether NodeJs is Synchronous or Asynchronous and whether JavaScript is Synchronous or Asynchornous.

Comment: What does it even mean for a runtime environment or programming language to be synchronous or asynchronous? A function call can be synchronous (blocking) or asynchronous (non-blocking).The whole statement is nonsense. Do you have some links or quotes?

Answer (score 4):

Those websites are giving you bad information.

JavaScript engines run a single main event loop. It can do only one thing at a time (i.e. is synchronous). If it isn't doing anything, then it will be checking queues to see if any tasks from outside the main event loop need picking up. Almost all the JavaScript you write will run on that main event loop.

Some JavaScript will interact with APIs that do stuff outside the main event loop. Examples include:

- Using `setTimeout` to queue a function to run later
- Using an API (such as `fetch` which is provided by web browsers and node.js) to make a network request
- Using an API (such as `fs.readFile` which is provided by node.js or `FileReader` which is provided by web browsers) to read a file.
- Using a worker thread (node) or web worker (browsers) to run JS outside the main event loop and to listen for messages that come back from it

These are asynchronous (because the JS function you call to trigger them *just* triggers them; it doesn't pause the main event loop to wait for the response).

Asynchronous APIs are not unique to Node.js.